# Accessing Windows "current directory" per drive using Linux path syntax

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, git

I’m on a Windows system, using the `cmd` shell and running the excellent Linux-style command-line tools such as `grep` and `diff` that come with Git for Windows. These tools expect file and directory arguments to use the Linux path syntax, and don’t understand the Windows path syntax at all.

In Windows `cmd`, each drive letter has its own current directory. For this example, let’s suppose the current directory on drive C is `C:\foo` and the current directory on drive D is `D:\bar`. Let’s suppose my current drive is C:

```
C:\foo>_
```

Now suppose I want to run a command-line tool against a file in the *current directory of a drive other than my current drive*.

With a command-line program that understands Windows syntax, such as `find`, I could say:

```
C:\foo>find "something" d:somefile
```

and the lack of a backslash would indicate that `somefile` is relative to the current directory on drive D, namely `D:\bar\somefile`.

How can I do this with a tool that requires the Linux syntax, say, `grep` under Git for Windows? I know how to specify the absolute path:

```
C:\foo>grep <something> /d/bar/somefile
```

but suppose I (or my batch file) don’t know the absolute path, or it’s really long and I don’t want to type it. What is the relative corollary to the absolute `/d/bar/somefile`, specifying the drive letter `D`, but not the directory `bar`?

This is especially relevant if the command is something like `diff`, operating on two files that are on the respective “current directory” of two different drives, so “just change your current drive” doesn’t solve the problem.

I apologize for the length of this question, but wanted to make sure the scenario was well explained. I can’t find this anywhere using Google or other search engines.

Answer (score 0):

The Unix path syntax doesn't permit referring to the current directory of a given drive because Unix doesn't have the concept of drives.  All paths exist in a single hierarchy, starting at `/`, and all disks of any sort are mounted somewhere within this hierarchy.  There are certainly conventions for where those paths are mounted on a given OS, but Unix systems don't intrinsically require them to be in any particular location.  Typically on Unix, the same kinds of data always live in the same location in the file system on different machines, even if those machines have chosen to store those data with different sets of physical drives.

Unix systems do have the concept of the current directory, which is written `.` (a single dot), and the parent directory, which is written `..` (two dots).  Note the use of "the": there is but a single current directory per process, not one per drive.  You can refer to files relative to the current directory, such as `./foo/bar/baz`, or to the parent directory, such as `../../foo`.

You could try using symbolic links if the problem is that the directory is too long and inconvenient to work with and you'll be doing it often, but on Windows that requires elevated privileges or developer mode.  Other than that, you'll have to specify either an absolute or relative path if you want to refer to another drive's current directory.